Difficulty understanding a contour integral regarding the Riemann Zeta Function
While studying the Riemann zeta function one often finds himself considering the integral going from $+\infty$ to $0$, circling the origin and then going back from $0$ to $+\infty$, this makes sense to me until the radius of the circle around the origin goes to zero, wouldn't this mean that we are integrating the same function, firs from $+\infty$ to $0$ and then from $0$ to $+\infty$? Shouldn't this integral be null?
To be clearer I will lay out an example, this is from "Titchmarsh The theory of the Riemann Zeta function":
He considers the integral:
$$I(s)=\int_{C}\frac{z^{s-1}}{e^z-1}dz$$
where the contour C is the one I mentioned, he goes ahead proving that the integral on the circle, goes to zero with the radius going to zero, this is clear to me and all is calculations seem valid.
He proceeds to write:
$$I(s)=-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(xe^{2\pi i})^{s-1}}{e^x-1}dx$$
First I don't understand where the factor $e^{2\pi i}$ is coming from, second isn't it just $1$?
Isn't it true that:
$$e^{i\pi}=-1$$
and therefore
$$e^{2 i \pi}=-e^{i\pi}=1$$
so that $I(s)=0$ like I said?
I truly think that I'm making some kind of basic mistake, but I really can't seem to find it.

How do you define $x^{s-1}$? When you understand that, you understand the integral (hint - on the contour the branch of the logarithm used changes when you go around the origin)

Thank you for your reply, I understand that the logaritihm changes when you go around the origin, my point is that in the example I brought up and in all other examples of this calculation, the radius of the circle goes to $0$, if that is the case wouldn't the two branches collapse into one? and then would it make sense to have a definition of Logarithm when we go from $+\infty$ to $0$ and a different one when we go from $0$ to $+\infty$ on the same line?

The point is to have a continuous integrand in the integration variable and analytic in the free variable to get an analytic result so yes you have different branches but they need to be connected by the circle - taking the circle radius to zero transfers the singularity into the integral expression so to speak hence the final result is what you get
